# How to save base64 string as an image into a folder in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to save a base64 string as an image into a folder on server and database using C#. But I am getting 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.' Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code?

My Controller:

```
    public ActionResult ShareProduct(Product item, PhotoProduct prphoto, string[] Photo)
    {
    foreach (string file in Photo)
            {
                if (file != null)
                {
                    string base64 = file.Substring(file.IndexOf(',') + 1); 
                    base64 = base64.Trim('\0'); 
                    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64); 
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
                    {
                        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
                        string newPhoto = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png";
                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"));
                        image.Save("~/Uploads/" + newPhoto);
                        prphoto.ImageName = "/Uploads/" + newPhoto;
                    }
                     }
                      }
```

Debug result:

[image]

Comment: A base64 string is not an image.  If you want to save an image as a base64 string read your memory stream as input and convert to a base64 string.

Comment: It's not a good idea to save files to the application folder. It will complicate deployments (because now you can't just wipe the directory and xcopy the whole build output) and you may introduce security holes related to unchecked path construction.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Is there safe way to save it to database?

Comment: What is the format of that Image? Have you tried to convert and show it somewhere else? You `Path.Combine()` is weird and `image.Save("~/Uploads/" + newPhoto);` is probably supposed to used it instead of hard-coding `"~/Uploads/"`, which is weirder. GDI+ won't be happy about that.

Comment: There's no need to use `Image` as an intermediary if you're going to save it to a database. Just pass `imageBytes` as a BLOB parameter (`varbinary(max)` in SQL Server, `BLOB` in Oracle, etc.) when you insert the record.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I solved it and posted answer here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by changing the code like below. But I'm not sure if it's safe. It works fine for now.

```
   string base64 = file.Substring(file.IndexOf(',') + 1);
   base64 = base64.Trim('\0');
   string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".Jpeg";
   byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
   ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
   System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);
    image.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"+fileName), 
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    prphoto.ImageName = "/Uploads/" + fileName;
```